# Trying to understand forking and the relationship between the parent and the child process

Tags: c, process, fork, parent-child

So I am trying to understand the forking process and in the following program. I have a global integer that gets manipulated by both the parent and the child processes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib> 


using namespace std;


int global = 0;

int main()
{

    int fork_return;


    fork_return = fork();

    if(fork_return == 0)
    {
        global++;
        printf("Global value in child is: %d \n", global);
    }
    else
    {
        global--;
        printf("Global value in parent is: %d \n", global);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Inside the child process, global is 1

Inside the parent process,  global is -1

My question is: How come we have a global variable and what happens to the child is basically hidden from the parent and vice versa?

My understanding is: What happens in the child is hidden from the parent and vice versa.

Why this behavior ?

Comment: They Are Different Processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent and child have an identical view of memory and file descriptors at the time `fork` is called. After that, they are each free to go their own separate ways. The `fork` operation would be unusable otherwise as any change in one process would corrupt what the other one was doing.